# Get modified element in HTML slot

Tags: javascript, html, custom-component

I am trying to create a custom HTML component which creates tabs for every child element that it has. Here is the code for that custom component:

```js
const code_window = document.getElementById("window");
class CodeWindow extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({
            mode: 'open'
        });
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(code_window.content.cloneNode(true));
        this.code = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("code");
        this.tabbar = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("tabbar");
        this.code.addEventListener("slotchange", e => {
            var elems = e.target.assignedNodes();
            for (let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                var tab = document.createElement("div");
                tab.classList.add("tab");
                var name = elems[i].getAttribute("name");
                tab.innerHTML = name;
                tab.setAttribute("name", name);
                this.tabbar.appendChild(tab);
                if (elems[i].hasAttribute("active")) this.activateTab(name);
                tab.addEventListener("click", e => this.activateTab(e.target.getAttribute("name")));
            }
            if (!this.previous_tab && this.tabbar.children.length > 0) this.activateTab(this.tabbar.children[0].getAttribute("name"));
        });
    }
    activateTab(name) {
        if (this.previous_tab) {
            this.previous_frame.removeAttribute("active");
            this.previous_tab.removeAttribute("active");
        }
        var tabs = this.tabbar.children,
            frames = this.code.assignedElements();
        for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            if (tabs[i].getAttribute("name") == name) {
                tabs[i].setAttribute("active", "");
                frames[i].setAttribute("active", "");
                this.previous_frame = frames[i];
                this.previous_tab = tabs[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
customElements.define("c-window", CodeWindow);
```

```html
<template id="window">
    <style>
        :host {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        #titlebar {
            display: flex;
            background-color: green;
        }
        #tabbar {
            flex-grow: 1;
            display: flex;
        }
        #tabbar .tab {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            background-color: #bbb;
        }
        #tabbar .tab[active] {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        #code {
            flex-grow: 1;
            display: block;
            position: relative;
        }
        #code::slotted(*) {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            padding: 5px;
            display: none;
        }
        #code::slotted(*[active]) {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="titlebar">
        <div id="tabbar"></div>
    </div>
    <slot id="code" name="frames"></slot>
</template>
<c-window style="border: 2px solid green; height: 300px;">
    <div slot="frames" name="Content 1">Contents of tab 1</div>
    <div slot="frames" name="Content 2">Contents of tab 2</div>
</c-window>
```

There is a slot inside the custom component and I want that every time a child element is added, a tab should be added, if a child element is removed, the tab associated with that child should be removed.

But the `slotchange` event carries no information about which element has been added/removed, so currently, I have to loop through the `slot.assignedElements()` every time `slotchange` event is called and create tabs for each and every element. It means that for a particular child, duplicate tabs will be created, which can also be quite CPU intensive.

So, I was thinking if there is some way to get the information about the modified element so that the action can be performed on only the modified element. Is there any way of getting only the modified element? If not, what method can I apply for achieving this?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: No, you have to do your own bookkeeping based on ``assignedNodes``; its as easy as setting a property on the nodes your processed. Your (hoisted) ``var`` instead ``let``usage takes more CPU cycles.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the oldskool *Switch-DIVs* approach for Tabs

You can do it all with **one** shadowDOM `<slot ="active">`

and **one** click handler

Needs some more work; but you get the `slot="active"` concept

```html
<template id="TABS-MEISTER">
  <style>
    #bar { display:flex }
    #bar div { width: 100px; background: lightgreen ; margin-right:1em ; cursor:pointer}
  </style>
  <div id="bar"></div>
  <div style="clear:both"><slot name="active"></slot></div>
</template>
<tabs-meister>
  <div title="Tab1">Tab #1</div>
  <div slot="active" title="Tab2">Tab #2</div>
  <div title="Tab3">Tab #3</div>
</tabs-meister>
<script>
  customElements.define('tabs-meister', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      let template = (id) => document.getElementById(id).content.cloneNode(true);
      super()
        .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
        .append(template(this.nodeName));
      this.onclick = (evt) => {
        if (this.activetab) this.activetab.removeAttribute("slot");
        let tab = evt.composedPath()[0];
        this.activetab = this.querySelector(`[title="${tab.title}"]`);
        this.activetab.slot = 'active';
      }
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      let tabs = [...this.children].map(node => {
          return `<div title=${node.title}>${node.title}</div>`;
      }).join ``;
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#bar").innerHTML = tabs;
    }
  });
</script>
```